# attaching preventDefault; to .live('click', function( )

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, progressive-enhancement

i keep getting a sytax error when trying to add `(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;`  to

```
$("#pegasus-tile, #o-w, #next-pidu, #prev-bgapp").live('click',     function() {
        $("#proj-content").load("projects/pegasus.html", function() {

        $('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>');
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'sliceUpDown'
        });
    });
});
```

im not sure how to combine it when using `.live`, i know its somthing really simple but i just cant get it, any helps much apreciated

Comment: Are you aware that `live` is deprecated? You should be using `on` instead. If you're stuck on an older version of jQuery, you can use `delegate` instead.

Comment: @james i was aware but for some reason using .on dosnt work, im using 1.7.2, is it just a straight forward swap .live for .on or is there more to it ?

Comment: There is more to it - you need to pass a selector as the 2nd argument to `on`. That selector should match an ancestor element to which the event handler will be delegated.

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/live/ (scroll down a little) to see how to convert `.live` to `.on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple:

```
$("#pegasus-tile, #o-w, #next-pidu, #prev-bgapp").live('click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#proj-content").load("projects/pegasus.html", function() {

        $('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>');
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'sliceUpDown'
        });
    });
});
```